# Multiple pipes on writeStream open event gives undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs, serverside-javascript

I am downloading a file from a URL and then I want to write the metadata for that file to the destination stream only after I make sure that the destination file is created(i.e. after fs.createWriteStream(path) is successful).So I have used the "open" event of writable stream to proceed further. However, this code gives me the error exactly on the second pipe:

```
Cannot call method 'pipe' on undefined
```

There is more code beyond this which uses the hashes that are calculated here. But somehow I am stuck with this error at the moment. I have been struggling on this for quite a while. Any help/pointers are very much appreciated.

Also I tried to run the example

```
var fs = require('fs');
var digestStream = require('digest-stream')
callHandle();


function callHandle(){
   var stream  = request.get(url)
   var result = {}
   handle(reader, result)
}

function handle(reader,metadata){
const writer = fs.createWriteStream('pathToFile');
writer.on('open', function(){
    reader.pipe(
        digestStream('sha1', 'hex', function(digest, length) {
            result.sha1 = digest;
            result.size = length;
        }))
        .pipe(
            digestStream('md5', 'hex', function(digest) {
                result.md5 = digest;
            })
        ).pipe(writer)
   })
  }
```

Comment: `handle(reader, result)` should be `handle(stream, result)`?